# How can I force graphql-ws to use Websocket over Http/2?

Tags: websocket, apollo-client, traefik, http2, graphql-js

I have a GraphQL Server and the goal is to switch it to http/2.

The full setup would look like this:

1. Backend Server Http/2 only
2. Traefik as Reverse Proxy (with TLS) using [h2c:// prefix](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/user-guides/grpc/#with-http-h2c) to the backend server.
3. Clients negotiating protocol with Traefik (Result: Http/2) and making a http/2 request which gets forwarded to the backend server.

Basically, all these points work already. But only for normal HTTP Requests. Not for WebSockets (needed for GraphQL Subscriptions).

With curl --verbose I can see:

```
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
...
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
```

So this part works great. ALPN actually offers http/2 (h2) and the Browser actually chooses it. (When the apollo-client makes a request, the browser network tab shows **h2**).

For whatever reason, this is not the case with WebSockets (using graphql-ws). The network tab shows a Http1.1/GET Request with the "Upgrade: WebSocket" Header. This just fails with a 500. (on server side: invalid http2 preface)

WebSockets do have support to use a Http/2 Connection, which actually would be more efficient because of multiplexing. [WebSockets HTTP/2 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8441).
But that should show up as a http2/CONNECT Request.

Normally you should be able to use ALPN to let Server and Client negotiate the protocol, which for whatever reason works for the normal Requests but not the WebSockets...

A fallback would be to specifically tell the client to use http2 (e.g. with curl --http2-prior-knowledge).
But I can't find anything of that sort for the client (apollo-client using graphql-ws).

The alternative would be, running the backend server not just with http/2 but both (multi-use).
In desperation, I actually tried it and it worked. graphql-ws still tried to create WebSockets with http1.1/GET but now the server can still speak http1, so it worked...

But that requires ALPN on the backend server (meaning tls and certificates). Which is not a good solution. TLS should be managed on reverseproxy/loadbalancer level.

Additionally, there are these statements in the [Chromium Design Document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ZxaHz4j2BDMa1aI5CQHMjtFI3UxGT459pjYv4To9rFY/edit) for WebSockets over Http/2 that make me question whether this is even possible to control in the browser.

> This would only be used for secure WebSockets requests, and only if there is already an HTTP/2 connection where the server has already advertised support for WebSockets over HTTP/2 via the HTTP/2 SETTINGS parameter defined in the specification.  In other cases, a new non-HTTP/2 connection would be created to the origin, just like it is currently done.

> The initial implementation only uses existing HTTP/2 connections and only if the appropriate SETTINGS frame advertising WebSockets support has been received from the server.  A natural extension of this would would be to open HTTP/2 connections for WebSocket requests, for example, if the server has previously advertised WebSockets support.

It sounds like it's completely automatic, should the server have fulfilled specific requirements, that I don't quite understand how to diagnose or maybe even change something server-side to fulfill them.

I see 3 paths:

1. Somehow configure the graphql client to use http/2
2. Adjust the server so the browser chooses http/2 by itself.
3. Somehow realize multi-use on the backend server without the negatives

Does someone have any ideas for one of them?